# Python: Powerball Gen. Appending list of list

Tags: python, list, append

I am creating a power ball generator. I am very new to Python.

I want 5 list with 5 number plus power ball number. Everything works well until I try and add PB:(random int). I can get the PB:(#) to add to the end list(random_data). But having trouble adding PB:# to the end of every list(list_length) in the list(random_data).

Want: `[1,2,3,4,5,PB:8],[2,3,5,9,21,PB:4],...`

```
##

from random import randint
import random

print("PowerBall Generator")
number_of_lists=randint(5,5)

random_data = []
for number in xrange(0,number_of_lists):    
    list_length=randint(5,5)
    random_data.append(sorted(random.sample(xrange(54), list_length)))
for t in range(number_of_lists):
    for list in str(random_data):
        r=randint(1,31)
        list_length.append[str("PB: ")+str(r)]

for s in str(number_of_lists):
    print(random_data)
```

Comment: _having trouble adding PB:# to the end of every list(list_length) in the list(random_data)_, why? what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a lot more than is necessary.

There is no need for using `randint` if you are saying `randint(5,5)`, that means you want a random integer between 5 and 5, which is redundant.

`list_length.append[str("PB: ")+str(r)]`: here you are trying to type cast a string as a string which is also redundant and you also accidentally used brackets instead of parenthesis when calling the append method.

You also only need one loop to create your lists, in which we are appending the inner list by indexing the main list by the number of the loop we are on.

I believe the following accomplishes what you want.

```
from random import randint, sample

print("PowerBall Generator")

tickets = []
for number in range(5):    
    tickets.append(sorted(sample(range(54), 5)))
    r=randint(1,31)
    tickets[number].append("PB: " +str(r))

for ticket in tickets:
    print(ticket)
```